# I cannot change a font

Tags: interface

I have been trying to adjust something in the Udemy Blender Classes

In previous lectures, barely into some, the numbers in the lower left are referenced. This is something that appears on the header bar for a moment when making adjustments.

[image]

How do I adjust that? I have fixed the font sizes, added in a theme, but this one area remains pretty much unreadable.
CAN this even be adjusted? For me this is barely readable.
For all the times it HAS been referenced I can only think it will CONTINUE to be referenced and I sure would like to be able to read it.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't change the font size.

I think this is an issue with blender and should be fixed as soon as possible.

But if you think other way around, then the answer is, Yes. You can change it's color.

[image]

In themes, you can change is background color via `Header` and text color via `Header Text`. Both available in `3D View` category.

Comment: Outstanding!!
Thank you SO much! Yes, no size adjustment, but the color adjustment worked like a charm!